# Tailwind custom color is not active on hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I modified my `tailwind.config.js` to add a new custom color:

```js
module.exports ={
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        pepegray: { DEFAULT: "#323232" },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want my button to change color on hover.

```js
<button className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-silver hover:bg-pepegray m-0.5"></button>
```

But it doesn't work.

Funny thing is, if I write `bg-pepegray` it works. The only place it doesn't work is in the hover.

Comment: Are you sure the background color is not changing? Try increasing the width/height of the button. Also double-check the DOM to see if the class is being applied on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the pepegray it should be mentioned in ''(quotes) as 'pepegray'.
in HTML mentioned it as **'hover:bg-pepegray-DEFAULT'**

**in **tailwind.config.js****

```
module.exports ={
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'pepegray': { DEFAULT: "#323232" },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<button className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-silver hover:bg-pepegray-DEFAULT m-0.5"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no need to add a color pallete, you can remove object as a color value

```
module.exports ={
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        pepegray: "#323232",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in Angular. I restarted the development server and then it seemed to take effect. Other colors seemed to work without restart. Strange.